# Dynamic div tag onclick with param not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` while calling this function.I searched through the web but couldn't get the answer.Please any one help me to get rid of this

```
function getPostData() {
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
    $.ajax({
    url:'get_post_fun.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{post_id:post_id},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.success == true) {
            $("#post_title").val(res.post.p_title);
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(res.post.p_desc);
            $("#topics").val(res.post.topics);
            for(i=0; i<res.imgs.length; i++) {
                imgs_arr.push(res.imgs[i]);
                imgsdata += "<div id='media_div' class='col-md-3'>"+
                "<img src='uploads/"+ res.imgs[i] +"' width='90%'>"+
                "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove del_icon' onclick='delImgFun("+res.imgs[i]+")'></span></div>";
            }
            $("#media_blk").html(imgsdata);
        }
    },
    error:function(err) {
        console.log('error',err);
    }
})
```

}

Comment: Did you debug the code in `Chrome developer tools`?... can you please tell us at which line you are getting that error after debugging...

Comment: `onclick='delImgFun("+res.imgs[i]+")'` this line

Comment: What sort of thing does a `res.imgs[i]` contain? Is it a string?

Comment: @GummidiBhaskararao Can you respond? If you do it'll probably be very simple to solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Answering this question requires a full understanding of both front-end and back-end.
But you have just sent the front-end part. but I guess you need to pass some kind of authentication token to use this API (`get_post_fun.php`). It depends on the implementaion of your back-end. you may have to send it via request headers or a query string or payload of your request body.

Comment: I got the data successfully but that onclick in the div gives me the error

Answer (score -1):

Normal click is not working with dynamic content so you need to use like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var spanTag = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove del_icon' id='clickBtn'>Click Btn</span></div>";

$('.staticDiv').html(spanTag);

$('body').on('click', '#clickBtn', function(){
 alert('this will work for dynamic content');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="staticDiv"></div>
```